# SOAP клиент для Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap

Доброе время суток,

Мне нужно подключиться к SOAP и получить данные:
http://vipsms.net/api/soap.html

Для этого я создаю в Visual Studio новый проект C# Windows Forms, далее в Обозревателе решений подключаю службу, и оно даже находит сервисы:

[image: Подключение службы]

Но почему-то возникает ошибка и прокси-класс для роботы со службой не генерируется:

[image: Ошибка]

В чем может быть дело? И как правильно обмениваться запросами с SOAP в Visual Studio? Может есть более легкие решения?

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на службу [так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb628649.aspx). Вариант устаревший, но у меня сработал, а для нормального варианта сервис не предоставляет метаданные, поэтому генератор кода ни чего сделать может.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Может проще написать какой-то парсер для разбора ответов от сервера? Просто не могу найти библиотек для работы с SOAP в Visual Studio. Они вообще существуют?)

Comment: WCF и создавали, в частности, для работы с SOAP. Можно воспользоваться SoapUI для тестирования отправки запросов, а заодно подсмотреть параметры post-запроса к сервису. Отдельную библиотеку для SOAP у MS я не находил, может сторонее что-то есть, но я не в курсе.

Comment: Значит дело в самом сервере, ибо подключаю все по инструкции и оно не может сгенерировать для него прокси-классы :-)